# How do i target a unique id of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

My goal is to target unique id of a button using jquery.

For example

```
<button id="5412313">Remove</button>
<button id="9882813">Remove</button>
<button id="123123123">Remove</button>
<button id="214343">Remove</button>
<button id="3434343">Remove</button>
<button id="4343434">Remove</button>
```

Jquery

```
$("#WhatshouldIputInHere?").on("click", function(){
  console.log($(this));
});
```

Comment: `$("#5412313")` and `$("#9882813")`

Comment: It is not flexible, What if I have 100 buttons.

Comment: $("button").on("click", function(){
  $(this).remove();
});

Comment: @guradio: `#5412313` is an invalid selector. jQuery lets you get away with it, as a byproduct of optimizing it, but I wouldn't recommend invalid selectors.

Comment: @sinusGob do you know what a class is?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You've said you want to target a unique button, but then you've said that targeting a unique button isn't flexible enough. So...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Target a button with unique id.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes you are correct so he should first fix how he names the `ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `remove()`.

```
$("button").on("click", function(){
 $(this).remove(); 
 //$(this).attr('id');
});
```

Based on your button label i came to know this.you can do anything with your id which i have commanded .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `event` object in the handler function, the code is like this:

```
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    alert(event.target.id);
})
```

[Here's the effect of the code above](https://jsfiddle.net/david3310273/tLLcahh6/#&togetherjs=JoAPNo748f)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button').on('click',function(){
    console.log($(this));
    if($(this).attr('id')=='9882813'){
        console.log('button with id '+$(this).attr('id')+'clicked');
    }
});
```